# Grant Stores not being called when authenticating with Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have setup Identity Server 4 with customized stores for authorization codes, refresh tokens, reference tokens and user consents. They are setup this way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddScoped<IUserRequester, UserRequester>(_ =>
        new UserRequester(Configuration.GetSection("AzureTableStore.UserLogin").Get<TableStoreConfiguration>()));
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

    X509Certificate2 certData = DownloadCertificate(Configuration.GetSection("APICertificate").Get<Secret>());
    IIdentityServerBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(certData);
    builder.AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get());
    builder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Identities.Get());
    builder.AddInMemoryApiResources(Apis.GetResources());
    builder.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Apis.GetScopes());

    builder.Services.Configure<TableStoreConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureTableStore.UserLogin"));
    builder.Services.Configure<RedisConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("RedisCache"));
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IRedisConnection, RedisConnection>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRequester, UserRequester>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, PasswordValidator>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationCodeStore, AuthorizationCodeStore>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IReferenceTokenStore, ReferenceTokenStore>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IRefreshTokenStore, RefreshTokenStore>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserConsentStore, UserConsentStore>();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {

        // Set the swagger doc stub
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "Authentication"
        });

        // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        string xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        string xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Authentication v1"));
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Authentication API v1");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));
}
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I debug into the service when authenticating a user, I notice that none of my stores are called. Furthermore, I notice that Identity Server logs that it's still using the in-memory grant store.

```
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Starting IdentityServer4 version 4.1.2+997a6cdd643e46cd5762b710c4ddc43574cbec2e
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using the default authentication scheme idsrv for IdentityServer
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: \Authentication\Authentication
```

So then, how do I tell Identity Server that it should use my stores? I've followed the guide, [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/identity-server/creating-your-own-identityserver4-storage-library), and it seems to indicate that I need custom impelmentations of `IPersistedGrantStore` and `IPersistedGrantService` but I can't fathom why I should need both. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: That config looks OK to me, are you definitely using a grant type that would employ one of these? I.e. generating auth codes or refresh tokens?

Comment: @mackie The grant type I'm using is `password`, which should rely on the `IAuthorizationCodeStore`.

Comment: As in ResourceOwnerPassword? If so, not it will not need to use any stores at all - it will just issue a JWT which does not require any backend persistence. Hybrid or authorization code will generate authorization codes and potentially refresh tokens too.

Comment: @mackie Ah, I see. But if that's the case then shouldn't that access token be stored somewhere so that it could be verified when the token is sent to an endpoint?

Comment: JWT bearer tokens don't need storing as verification is done via the signature and claims inside only.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, why am I receiving the message that the in-memory grant store is being used?

Comment: Can you share the logs messages in question please?

Comment: @mackie I updated the question with my logs

Comment: I have answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our solution I just implemented `IPersistedGrantStore` and didn't override the individual ones like you have. That service is the thing that actually does the persistence for auth codes, reference tokens, refresh tokens and consent and also allows for retrieval and removal of all persisted grants associated with a user so I think you'll have to provide your own implementation.

In short and as Scott said in the linked article:

> The default implementations of IAuthorizationCodeStore,
> IRefreshTokenStore, IReferenceTokenStore, and IUserConsentStore all
> utilise the IPersistedGrantStore

you don't need both, you only need to implement `IPersistedGrantStore`.